# Eclipse Android launcher shows home screen, not my application

Tags: android, eclipse

When I launch my android application from eclipse, it shows the home screen, and I then need to unlock the screen and go to my app. I would like it to just show my app by default.

I have tried right clicking on the app and selecting Run As..., but Android Application is not a choice there. I need to manually create a new Android run configuration for my application and then I launch that.

Is there a way to just make my app show by default? I'm running with the emulator for Android version 2.2?

Note: I'm also getting an error that says "Emulator] Unknown savevm section type 95" which I'm not sure what that means yet

thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emulator always starts with the screen locked. Unlock it and wait a moment, sometimes it needs a minute to launch your app. If it doesn't work after a few moments, leave the emulator open and try running it again. If it doesn't launch now, there's something wrong.

Comment: When I run apps from Eclipse, my emulator NEVER loads up with the screen locked.  (Naturally it takes ages for it to LOAD, but when it displays the screen, it's the home screen and then my app pops up)  But then I leave the emulator open after running my app so I don't have to wait through the loading time every debug...  Although I've read that there are some issues with the newest release of the ADK..

Comment: Really? Every time I use it the screen is ALWAYS locked. Weird.

Comment: I think I was just impatient. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, now I'm not sure. It seemed to auto load it once, maybe I clicked something by mistake. Now I'm at the locked screen ... I was hoping it could autounlock, but either way, I have it running from the apps screen.

Comment: I've never really looked into the locked screen thing, it's just always been there for me. After the screen unlocks, it always runs my app, though.

Comment: The reason it wasn't launching locked for you was you had it restoring from a saved state before. It's showing the lock screen now because it isn't restoring from the prior state. You're getting the "Unknown savevm section type 95" error because it can't restore the former state for some reason. A lot of people have been experiencing that since the new tools came out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you either didn't create your project as an android project to begin with, or if you did you didn't create a starting activity (or deleted the one that you did create)?  Either way, you probably need to go edit your AndroidManifest.xml file and add an intent filter to an activity.  Just guessing.  Should look similar to this:

```
    <activity
      android:name={String for the name of your app}
      android:label={String for the name displayed on the icon}>
      <intent-filter>
        <action
          android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category
          android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

** posted before your edit ^^^

In terms of your error, I have no clue what that is, so maybe it has nothing to do with your AndroidManifest, then.  :T

Comment: Googling the error ("Android Unknown savevm section type 95"), one of the links says it might be caused by having your emulator save a snapshot of itself.  Have you tried turning that functionality off?

Comment: Here's the URL to the error that I googled, if you want to look at it.  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18366

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest, and make sure your activity has the correct intent-filter

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
        </intent-filter>
```

BTW, Previous to Android 1.6 i think the emulator always started with the screen locked then they changed that and it starts with your app

Comment: I'm running with the latest SDK and an app that targets API 10 and running an emulator with API 10 and it starts with the screen locked.